# How can I get current version of custom plugin in wordpress

Tags: wordpress

I want to compare the current version of my custom plug-in with update version of plug-in.

I get updated version of plug-in in response from server.

How can I get current version of my plug-in?

Answer (score 9):

You can use `get_file_data()` [function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_file_data/) which is available on frontend and backend. For example:

```
get_file_data('/some/real/path/to/your/plugin', array('Version'), 'plugin');
```

Answer (score 3):

if you use `get_plugin_data()` on the frontend it will throw an error `Call to undefined function get_plugin_data()`. Here is the correct way to get plugin header data.

```
if ( is_admin() ) {
    if( ! function_exists( 'get_plugin_data' ) ) {
        require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/plugin.php' );
    }
    $plugin_data = get_plugin_data( __FILE__ );

    echo "<pre>";
    print_r( $plugin_data );
    echo "</pre>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could save you version in the [options](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/update_option) table for easy retrieval. But you can also use [get_plugin_data](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_plugin_data) for more details about a given plugin.

```
<?php

    $data = get_plugin_data( "akismet/akismet.php", false, false );

?>
```

Please note that get_plugin_data is only available in the WordPress admin, it's not a front-end available function.

Answer (score -1):

For users who land on this question to find out the current version of WordPress itself use this function.

```
// it will show only numeric value i.e 5.8.2
echo get_bloginfo( 'version' );
```